# Call Microsoft graph API using Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to access Microsoft Graph API using Access token of b2c login.
Following are the endpoints azure portal showing.
[image]

As I feel we must be able to call https://graph.microsoft.com endpoints according to this. Please correct me if I am wrong. Then I generated access token as follows and Tried to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ using that token.

[image]

The result is as follows.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-08-25T11:58:07",
      "request-id": "c6a9ba06-d41e-49f7-ba94-f75478ce89b0"
    }
  }
}
```

I have granted API permissions as follows in my application too
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont work. Use the Azure AD flows in your AAD B2C tenant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: I think azure has updated some of the things related to b2c. The endpoints list I have added in the question has mentioned about graph API too. Anyway b2c token is not allow to call graph API.

Comment: Key point - B2C token is not accepted by Graph API. B2C token is issued by endpoints in your screenshot. Therefore - it will not work like this.