# Use Access Token for Graph API in AAD B2C

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

The access token that the app receives after successful authentication, can we use the same token for invoking GRAPH APIs for /me.

I tried to use the access token that I received in POSTMAN for /me but got an invalid token error. If I explicitly generate the token in POSTMAN, I am able  to use it for /me.

What am I doing wrong here?[image]!

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the error in Postman?

Comment: Updated with error screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579290/call-microsoft-graph-api-using-azure-b2c. And see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62275609/no-access-token-returned-for-ad-b2c-user-when-requesting-microsoft-graph-delegat/62275744?r=SearchResults#62275744

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it.The access token you get after successful authentication of the app you use should be `b2c`, while `b2c` cannot be used to request a graph endpoint. See reference from [Azure AD B2C auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow).
[image]

[image]
You can successfully request `/me` endpoint with the explicitly generated access token in POSTMAN because you are using an access token from [Azure AD auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).