# Access Azure AD-Protected API When User in and Client App Registered in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an API protected by Azure AD. The use case I am trying to implement is one where a user in a B2C tenant, that has signed into an app registered in the same tenant needs the client app to call the API protected in the Azure AD tenant. What OAuth2 grant type will make this possible between both tenants? I have second scenario just like this except the client app in the AAD B2C tenant does SAML2 and not OAuth2.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: did you come right eventually? Looking to achieve something similar myself: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121290/allow-azure-b2c-app-registration-access-to-regular-organization-ad-app-registrat

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example using Azure API [management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Here's another in the context of the [user](https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/).

SAML is different in that the token returned by the authentication is a SAML token (in XML), not a JWT. Never tried using this to call an API.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions and I thank you very much. However, remember I mentioned the existence of an Azure AD tenant, where the API is registered? I was wondering if there was an option where there could be a token exchange between the AAD B2C  and AAD tenants that ends in the AAD tenant issuing an access token that can be used to access the API.

Comment: Will appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579290/call-microsoft-graph-api-using-azure-b2c

Comment: So you have to follow the links above - get an AAD JWT to access an AAD resource.