# Auth setup of B2C Web API accessing confidential client (multitenant) Web API

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have a multi-tenant Web API of **tenant A**. It has [permissions exposed and accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74265604/3951987) by a B2C Web API of **tenant B**. (The API App Services live in the same tenant, but their AD instances are separate due to the one being a B2C tenant).

I have the following code in my B2C Web API authenticating with **tenant B** to access the multi-tenant Web API of **tenant A**.

I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Web (v1.25.5) and .NET Core (6), and so I don't have to handle making unnecessary calls to get an access token, I'm using the IDownstreamWebApi helper classes (though I have tried without according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore), but land up with the same error.)

**My code:**

**appsettings.json**

[image]

**program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
    },
    options => { 
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); 
    })
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
})
.AddDownstreamWebApi("TenantAApi", options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("TenantAApi", options);
})
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

**Calling code:**

```
var response = await _downstreamWebApi.CallWebApiForAppAsync(
          "TenantAApi",
          options =>
          {
              options.HttpMethod = httpMethod;
              options.RelativePath = url;
          }, content);

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The error I receive:

```
MSAL.NetCore.4.48.0.0.MsalClientException: 
     ErrorCode: tenant_override_non_aad
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: WithTenantId can only be used when an AAD authority is specified at the application level.
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1.WithTenantId(String tenantId)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForAppAsync(String scope, String authenticationScheme, String tenant, TokenAcquisitionOptions tokenAcquisitionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Web.DownstreamWebApi.CallWebApiForAppAsync(String serviceName, String authenticationScheme, Action`1 downstreamWebApiOptionsOverride, StringContent content)
```

What doesn't make sense is that I'm calling this from a B2C Web API, from what I can see in the existing [AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/a19b2887bc5353e9301f929965dab0990bbcc745/src/client/Microsoft.Identity.Client/ApiConfig/AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder.cs#L292) (see line 292), B2C authorities are not AAD specific, and even so, adding an `Authority` or `AadAuthorityAudience` to my `AzureAdB2C` config object has no effect.

Am I missing a configuration property somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this isn't possible according to the following wiki post -

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/b2c-limitations#azure-ad-b2c-protected-web-apis-cannot-call-downstream-apis

For now I'm going to try a different approach and get an access token with a ConfidentialClientApplication object, and if that doesn't work, create a separate app registration in the other tenant and authenticate with that instead.